# How do I get the "net send" messenger service working on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, services, netsend

When trying to use the method below to send message in Windows 7 nothing happens.

> net send

It seems the Messenger Service is not working. Any suggestions as to why?

Answer (score 24):

**Net send** is no longer used; it wasn't used in Windows Vista either. Try using the **msg** command, instead. You can find more information [here](http://www.petri.co.il/msg-exe-net-send-vista.htm).

Answer (score 9):

**The MSG command is only available on Ultimate and Business versions**!

So stop looking for it if you have a basic edition. If you need a LAN messenger you have other tools such as WinMessenger or [dMessage](http://eng.dmessage.com).

But it's not free, depends on your needs ... :/

Answer (score 3):

To use this command in Windows 7 follow what I display down below.

Click the Windows logo in the taskbar to open the startmenu. Once in there, type **"CMD"** in the search box, and then push <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now once in the **command prompt** or **CMD window**. Type in **"MSG"** and push <kbd>Enter</kbd> you will now see a list of commands which you can use for this command. In turn the MSG command with the right prefix will display a message on any or all computers connected to both the homegroup and the network.

Examples to use the command are below.

**MSG computername Do you see my message?**

If you use this command it will display the message on only the computer with that computername. If you want the message to band across the network use this command.

**MSG * Do you see my message?**

Please note if you want to write more then you'll have to type in **"MSG Computername"**, and then push <kbd>Enter</kbd>. From there you can type as much as you like but bare in mind that this is not like [MSN Messenger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Live_Messenger) because once you finish typing you have to push <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then **"Ctrl+Z"**. This will create a little symbol, like  **"^Z"**. Once that symbol has been created push <kbd>Enter</kbd> once more and there you go, the message or essay has been displayed. But if you don't do it this way you'll end up chopping your sentence or message up into a very short message. That's why if you have a paragraph you would like send over the network. Use this method instead of the method shown early in my reply.

Answer (score 0):

I've corresponded a bit with the author/s of WinSent Messenger (http://winsentmessenger.com/), whose freeware WinnoSent utility uses 'its own implementation of the "net send"' (quoted from their first email reply) so it doesn't need it.