# How to use the NET SEND command from Windows 7 to Windows XP?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, netsend

I want to use the [NET SEND](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_send.mspx?mfr=true) command to send a message from my machine to another in a local network. My machine is Windows 7 Home Premium, and I want to send a message to a Windows XP Home (SP2) machine. I know that NET SEND is no longer valid in Windows 7, so what can I use to communicate with Windows XP's NET SEND?

Comment: I thought the Messenger service was disabled in Windows XP already as well.

Comment: @Johannes Rossel:  I read something about that in an article somewhere that after XP SP1 was installed, the messenger service was disabled...I thought about mentioning it, but...so there is no netsend in XP SP2 or SP3?

Comment: I haven't used XP in years (luckily), but afair just the service was disabled by default. You could still *send* messages from that machine (while the functionality was removed from `net` as of Vista or so), even though you can't receive them anymore.

Comment: so you can send them from an XP machine but not receive them (on XP)?

Comment: Question was asked/answered a while ago: http://superuser.com/questions/38967/net-send-messenger-service-in-windows-7

Comment: @Joe Internet: I've already seen this question, and all it tells me is that Vista/7 do not support netsend, and MY question was about how I could overcome this, either with a hack or a third-party tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Service pack 2 the Messenger service got disabled by default.

To enable it type `services.msc` in `Run` and find the messenger service and enable it.
You'll need to enable it on both computers

Comment: can i enable it?

Comment: Yea type "services.msc" in Run and find the messenger service and enable it.

Comment: that easy? wow ok.  do I need to do it on the XP machine sending the netsend?

Comment: Yes. You need to enable it on both computers.

Comment: net start messenger, from command line, seeing as you'll be using it from that anyway.

Comment: `sc config messenger start= demand && sc start messenger`

Answer (score 2):

Sysinternals [PSTools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx) may be of some use for pranks such as these.

I once combined [PSExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) with a burp prank exe to very great effect, right up until the branch managing partner (law firm!) walked round the corner at a most inorportune moment! O_o

Answer (score 0):

`net send` no longer works from Windows XP.

As a replacement to `net send`, `msg.exe` was included in Professional editions in Windows Vista+.

Fetched from `msg /?`:

> ```
> Send a message to a user.
>
> MSG {username | sessionname | sessionid | @filename | *}
>    [/SERVER:servername] [/TIME:seconds] [/V] [/W] [message]
>
>  username            Identifies the specified username.
>  sessionname         The name of the session.
>  sessionid           The ID of the session.
>  @filename           Identifies a file containing a list of usernames,
>                      sessionnames, and sessionids to send the message to.
>  *                   Send message to all sessions on specified server.
>  /SERVER:servername  server to contact (default is current).
>  /TIME:seconds       Time delay to wait for receiver to acknowledge msg.
>  /V                  Display information about actions being performed.
>  /W                  Wait for response from user, useful with /V.
>  message             Message to send.  If none specified, prompts for it
>                      or reads from stdin.
> ```