# Send LAN messages

Tags: windows, lan, intranet, netsend

I would like to send message to targeted receivers.

I need to warn my users with LAN messages in case of breakdown of applications, and not mails because nobody read them!

Comment: More details please, especially about your infrastrucutre and used Operating Systems.

Comment: Guessing Windows, because it's tagged as "netsend".

Comment: @user61381 You need to tell us which version of windows you and your users are using.

Comment: Related question: [Net send & Messenger service in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/q/38967/36601)

Answer (score 1):

The below command will do what you want on a windows network, provided you have permissions and the admins have not blocked such messages.

```
NET SEND

{name | * | /DOMAIN[:name] | /USERS} message
```

Further information can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_send.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work if the OS is newer than XP SP2. On XP, since SP2, that service is disabled by default and on later operating systems, it has been removed because it was used for spamming!

Answer (score 1):

Was looking around and found this program: [Winsentmessenger](http://www.winsentmessenger.com/sent/)

It takes a bit of work to get setup, but it should work on all versions of windows. That being said, I would still recommend that you use OS provided services like "net send" or "msg" depending on your OS.

Answer (score 1):

You can't find `net send` under Windows 7 because it disappeared. but you can use software as desk alerts with `dmessage` to send lan message.